# String formatter IF the value is less than 10 add the leading zeros java in HH:MM:SS format with 3 variables syntax

Tags: java

I cannot find the proper syntax for a string format as well as setting it up for a output that adds the leading zeros IF the value inputted is less than 10.

Assume we are using a scanner to allow a user to input any value they want.

I want the output string to display the hours minutes and seconds in HH:MM:SS with leading zeros if the value for any of variables entered is less than  zero

Here is just a main method driver separate from entire main program as I am keeping code quarantined so that I don't get confused:

```
public class testString {
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
// variables assume that i am allowing scanner input, in main project, for now using 
 // dummy values in place of scanner
        int hours = 1;
        int minutes = 6;
        int seconds = 40;

   // format string to be corrected as well with allowing leading zeros if value is less 
 // than 10
     String output = String.format("%02d %02d %02", hours, minutes,
        seconds);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"%02d %02d %02"` you forgot a `d` at the end. Since you didn't specify what the problem is, I'll assume this should be closed as a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the last `d`.  Do it like this.  To ensure the field has leading zeros, put a `0` before the width specifier.

```
      String output = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes,
                seconds);
      System.out.println(output);
```

You can also do this by use the `System.out.printf()` method.

```
      System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d%n", hours, minutes,
                seconds);
```

For details, check out [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) in the Java API.